# iOS: How to display multiple images dynamiclly in imageview?

Tags: iphone

Hi I am new to iPhone.

What I need is, have to display only one image in one case, two images in another case like wise and for that I am using a `UIImageview` with `IBOutlet`.

How can I display multiple images in single imageview?

Please help me post some code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UIImageView` can only display one image at a time. You will either have to use several `UIImageView`s or compose your images into one file before displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should subviews ot type UIImageView to your main UIImageView.

The "hard" task will be to compute the boundaries of each subview, according to the prefered layout. Use the image property of UIImageView to set the image for each subview (don't worry about resizing, UIImageView will do the work for you)